# JQuery decorate buttons with spinner (do something before and after event)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$("#get-data").on("click", function() {
    const btn = $(this)
    const btnHtml = btn.html()

    btn.html($('#spinner-html').html())
    btn.prop('disabled', true)

     setTimeout(() => {
     // this is my ajax immitation
     
        // on ajax complete:
        btn.html(btnHtml)
        btn.prop('disabled', false)
     }, 2000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spinner-html" style="display: none">
 Loading...
</div>

<button id="get-data">Get Data</button>
```

I want each button that invokes ajax call to some API - being disabled and show spinner until API call complete.

The idea is to have it reusable. I.e. ajax part (represented as `setTimeout` here should not have any reference to the button clicked.

This works perfectly but I feel that repeating those 6 lines of code for button HTML for each button with ajax is a code duplication that can be avoided.

So I'd like to have it generic and reusable. I have tried this way (and some variations) but it didn't work...

```
function spinnerClick(b, f) {
    const btn = $(b)
    const btnHtml = btn.html()
    btn.html($('#spinner-html').html())
    btn.prop('disabled', true)
    f()
    btn.html(btnHtml)            // this goes immediately
    btn.prop('disabled', false)
}

function getData() {
    // all ajax stuff here
}

$('#get-data').on('click', function () {
    spinnerClick(this, getData)
})
```

Will appreciate any advice on that. Thanks!

**UPD**: JS fiddle added

Comment: jsfiddle will be very helpful, but I think if you make as many async await as required it will work.

Comment: If you use `await` it must be nested within a `async function`

Comment: @JafarJabr, jsfiddle added

Comment: @zer00ne, yes, I did inside `async` . But it anyway does it immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for adding jsfiddle, try this please!

```
function spinnerClick(b, f) {
    const btn = $(b)
    const btnHtml = btn.html()
    btn.html($('#spinner-html').html())
    btn.prop('disabled', true)
    f().then(() => {
      btn.html(btnHtml)
      btn.prop('disabled', false)
  });
}

function getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('hello');
      resolve(true);
     }, 2000);
    })
}

$('#get-data').on('click', function () {
    spinnerClick(this, getData)
})
```

Comment: Awesome! That's what I looked for. Thanks! this `then`/`Promise` thing I am not familiar with

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but why not just send the instance off to a separate function so you can access it when it resolves?

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    doAjax($(this));
  })
})

function doAjax(btn) {
  if (btn.find('span.spinner').length > 0) return console.log('wait, still running');
  btn.removeClass('finished').append('<span class="spinner"> * </span>');
  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.addClass('finished').find('span.spinner').remove()
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
.finished {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.spinner {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click 1</button>
<button>Click 2</button>
<button>Click 3</button>
```

Comment: but in this case, function that does ajax "knows" the button. This is exactly what I'd like to avoid. Logic of manipulating the button has to be outside ajax (in order to reuse it). I've also added jsfiddle to the question - maybe it will make it more clear